# Hibernate Save only Child table entry with parent foreign Key in Composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am starter in Hibernate & Spring MVC and struggling to find correct solution to my problem.
I have Parent Table (Events)and Child table (Votes). I want to save only child table entry whenever data is received from URL. I am having trouble in mapping relations and putting composite key to work

Following is my structure:

```
create table Events(
Event_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Event_Name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Event_options int(1) NOT NULL,
Start_TIME timestamp,
End_time   timestamp,
Active_Status int(1),
PRIMARY KEY(Event_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16
;

create table Votes(
Event_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
Voter_MSISDN int(13) NOT NULL,
Vote_Option int(1),
PRIMARY KEY(Event_ID,Voter_MSISDN),
FOREIGN KEY (Event_ID) REFERENCES Events(Event_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16
;
```

Events.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Events")
public class Events {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Event_ID")
    private Integer eventId;

    @Column(name="Event_Name")
    private String eventName;

    @Column(name="Event_options")
    private Integer eventOptions;

    @Column(name="Start_TIME")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "End_time")
    private String End_time;

    @Column(name="Active")
    private Integer status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Events")
    private Set<Votes> votes;
     //Setter Getters

}
```

Votes.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Votes")
public class Votes {

    public Votes(){}        

    @EmbeddedId
    private Vote vote;

    @Column(name = "Vote_Option")
    private int Vote_Option;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Event_ID")
    private Events events;

    //setters getters
}
```

Vote.java for Composite primary key setup through @Embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class Vote implements Serializable{

        public Vote(){}

        @Column(name="Event_ID")
        private int Event_ID;

        @Column(name="Voter_MSISDN")
        private long Voter_MSISDN;

        //setter getters
}
```

controller snippet for Adding Event and adding Vote

```
@RequestMapping(value="/AddEvent")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void AddEvent(@RequestParam(value = "ename", required = true) String ename, 
                        @RequestParam (value = "opt") String opt, 
                        @RequestParam (value = "stime") String start,
                        @RequestParam (value = "etime") String end,
                        @RequestParam (value = "status") String active){

        Events event = new Events();
        event.setEventName(ename);
        event.setEventOptions(Integer.parseInt(opt));
        event.setStartTime(start);
        event.setEnd_time(end);
        event.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(active));

        userDao.saveEvent(event);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Vote vote;

    @Autowired
    private Votes votes;

    @RequestMapping(value="/AddVote")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void AddVote(@RequestParam(value = "eventid",required = true) String eventid,
                        @RequestParam(value="msisdn") String msisdn,
                        @RequestParam(value = "opt")String opt){

        logger.info("Received parameters from URL "+eventid+" "+msisdn+" "+opt);
        vote.setEvent_ID(Integer.parseInt(eventid));


        vote.setVoter_MSISDN(Long.parseLong(msisdn));

        votes.setVote(vote);
        votes.setVote_Option(Integer.parseInt(opt));

        userDao.saveVotes(votes);           
    }
}
```

DAOImplementation:

```
@Transactional
    public void saveEvent(Events event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.save(event);

    }

    @Transactional 
    public void saveVotes(Votes votes){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.save(votes);
    }
```

The code is working fine whenever Event data is received and Event entry is added.
Not able to code correctly for Vote data. 
I want to insert just vote data whenever it is received from url. I have added Composite primary key to make sure unique entry for each event from one user(MSISDN).
Please suggest correct mapping for this model.
Any improvement suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need a composite key for this simple solution.

You have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Events")
public class Events {

    //....................

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Events")
    private Set<Votes> votes = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Simple just create a method in it which would create a new vote for that event. For e.g.:

```
public Vote createVote() {
    Vote vote = new Vote();
    vote.setEvent(this);
    votes.add(vote);
    return vote;
}
```

Then in your addVote controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/AddVote")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void AddVote(@RequestParam(value = "eventid",required = true) String eventid,
                    @RequestParam(value="msisdn") String msisdn,
                    @RequestParam(value = "opt")String opt){

    Event event = userDao.findEvent(eventid);
    Vote vote = event.createVote(); //This will create a vote for an event.

    vote.set.... //set your stuff.
    //It will cascade your vote to an event if you have a cascade sorted correctly as in the example above: cascade = CascadeType.ALL
}
```

Just make sure you got your transactions right. That's just an idea how it should be done.